# Show first option div as default after slicing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a small generator through perchance to help out fellow ttrpg players. I was asked to also add trackers, which I did, and it has an option to show divs depending on the amount of players. I found a nifty script somewhere here to make it work. However, I want to make the first div (or none at all) to show on page load before option is selected. I can't figure out how to do it :(

**SCRIPT:**

```
<script>

  $(".DropdownClass").change(function () {

    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'Count') {
        var number = $(this).val();
        $('.CommonAttribute').hide().slice( 0, number ).show();}});
      </script>
```

Selection and trackers:

```
<div ><select class="DropdownClass" name="Count" id="selectModelNumber">
         <option value="none" disabled selected>Number of players:</option>
         <option value="1">1 player</option>
    <option value="2">2 players</option>
    <option value="3">3 players</option>
    <option value="4">4 players</option>
    <option value="5">5 players</option>
    <option value="6">6 players</option>
         </select></div>

      <div class="none"></div>

<!-- 1 PLAYER -->

<div ><div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1"><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress1++; update(str1);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress1--; update(str1);">-</button>
  <input id="str1" oninput="stress1 = this.value" value="[outputstress1]"/></div>

<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth1++; update(stl1);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth1--; update(stl1);">-</button>
<input id="stl1" oninput="stealth1 = this.value" value="[outputstealth1]"/>
  </div></div>

  <!-- 2 PLAYERS -->

<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1"><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress2++; update(str2);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress2--; update(str2);">-</button>
  <input id="str2" oninput="stress2 = this.value" value="[outputstress2]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth2++; update(stl2);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth2--; update(stl2);">-</button>
<input id="stl2" oninput="stealth2 = this.value" value="[outputstealth2]"/>
  </div></div>


<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1" ><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress3++; update(str3);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress3--; update(str3);">-</button>
  <input id="str3" oninput="stress3 = this.value" value="[outputstress3]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth3++; update(stl3);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth3--; update(stl3);">-</button>
<input id="stl3" oninput="stealth3 = this.value" value="[outputstealth3]"/>
  </div></div>


<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1" ><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress4++; update(str4);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress4--; update(str4);">-</button>
  <input id="str4" oninput="stress4 = this.value" value="[outputstress4]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth4++; update(stl4);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth4--; update(stl4);">-</button>
<input id="stl4" oninput="stealth4 = this.value" value="[outputstealth4]"/>
  </div></div>


<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1" ><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress5++; update(str5);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress5--; update(str5);">-</button>
  <input id="str5" oninput="stress5 = this.value" value="[outputstress5]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth5++; update(stl5);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth5--; update(stl5);">-</button>
<input id="stl5" oninput="stealth5 = this.value" value="[outputstealth5]"/>
  </div></div>


<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1" ><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress6++; update(str6);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress6--; update(str6);">-</button>
  <input id="str6" oninput="stress6 = this.value" value="[outputstress6]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth6++; update(stl6);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth6--; update(stl6);">-</button>
<input id="stl6" oninput="stealth6 = this.value" value="[outputstealth6]"/>
  </div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to hide all the divs till the use selected then this might code might solve your problem.

just add this code:

`$('.CommonAttribute').hide();`

at the top before the change function this will hide all the divs with this class and it will not be shown until the user selected an option.

```js
$('.CommonAttribute').hide();

  $(".DropdownClass").change(function () {

    if ($(this).attr('name') == 'Count') {
        var number = $(this).val();
        $('.CommonAttribute').hide().slice( 0, number ).show();}});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ><select class="DropdownClass" name="Count" id="selectModelNumber">
         <option value="none" disabled selected>Number of players:</option>
         <option value="1">1 player</option>
    <option value="2">2 players</option>
    <option value="3">3 players</option>
    <option value="4">4 players</option>
    <option value="5">5 players</option>
    <option value="6">6 players</option>
         </select></div>

      <div class="none"></div>

<!-- 1 PLAYER -->

<div ><div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1"><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress1++; update(str1);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress1--; update(str1);">-</button>
  <input id="str1" oninput="stress1 = this.value" value="[outputstress1]"/></div>

<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth1++; update(stl1);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth1--; update(stl1);">-</button>
<input id="stl1" oninput="stealth1 = this.value" value="[outputstealth1]"/>
  </div></div>

  <!-- 2 PLAYERS -->

<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1"><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress2++; update(str2);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress2--; update(str2);">-</button>
  <input id="str2" oninput="stress2 = this.value" value="[outputstress2]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth2++; update(stl2);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth2--; update(stl2);">-</button>
<input id="stl2" oninput="stealth2 = this.value" value="[outputstealth2]"/>
  </div></div>


<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1" ><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress3++; update(str3);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress3--; update(str3);">-</button>
  <input id="str3" oninput="stress3 = this.value" value="[outputstress3]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth3++; update(stl3);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth3--; update(stl3);">-</button>
<input id="stl3" oninput="stealth3 = this.value" value="[outputstealth3]"/>
  </div></div>


<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1" ><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress4++; update(str4);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress4--; update(str4);">-</button>
  <input id="str4" oninput="stress4 = this.value" value="[outputstress4]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth4++; update(stl4);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth4--; update(stl4);">-</button>
<input id="stl4" oninput="stealth4 = this.value" value="[outputstealth4]"/>
  </div></div>


<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1" ><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress5++; update(str5);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress5--; update(str5);">-</button>
  <input id="str5" oninput="stress5 = this.value" value="[outputstress5]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth5++; update(stl5);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth5--; update(stl5);">-</button>
<input id="stl5" oninput="stealth5 = this.value" value="[outputstealth5]"/>
  </div></div>


<div style="display:inline-block;" class="CommonAttribute DivElement1" ><div style="float:left"><h2>Stress</h2>

<button onclick="stress6++; update(str6);">+</button>
<button onclick="stress6--; update(str6);">-</button>
  <input id="str6" oninput="stress6 = this.value" value="[outputstress6]"/></div>


<div style="float:left"><h2>Stealth</h2>

<button onclick="stealth6++; update(stl6);">+</button>
<button onclick="stealth6--; update(stl6);">-</button>
<input id="stl6" oninput="stealth6 = this.value" value="[outputstealth6]"/>
  </div></div>
```